# Type Error when using JwtSessionHandler - dart

Tags: types, dart, jwt

I have a problem with the dart types when using the JwtSessionHandler. I wanted to integrate user authentication and sessions using [this](https://bitbucket.org/andersmholmgren/shelf_auth/src/2343d20310b8c8477cd89ab5ad017eb6e6b9f97b/example/example_with_login_and_jwt_session.dart?at=master) example application from the [shelf_auth](https://bitbucket.org/andersmholmgren/shelf_auth) git repository as a guide.

Unfortunately I get an error when running the application (no syntax errors are detected before running the application)
The error message reads as follows:

```
Breaking on exception: object of type _TypeError: type '(String, String) => Future<UserLookupByUsernamePassword<Principal>>' is not a subtype of type 'UserLookupByUsernamePassword' of 'userLookup'.
```

The error originates from this line of code

```
var sessionHandler = new JwtSessionHandler('super app',new Uuid().v4(),testLookup.lookupByUsernamePassword);
```

to be precise from the last input argument of `JwtSessionHandler`
the `testLookup.lookupByUsernamePassword`. `testLookup` is defined by `var testLookup = new TestUserLookup();`

where

```
class TestUserLookup {
  Future<Option<Principal>> lookupByUsernamePassword(String username, String password) {
    final validUser = username == 'fred';
    final principalOpt = validUser ? new Some(new Principal(username)) : const None();

    return new Future.value(principalOpt);
  }

  Future<Option<Principal>> lookupByUsername(String username) {
    final validUser = username == 'fred';

    final principalOpt = validUser ? new Some(new Principal(username)) : const None();

    return new Future.value(principalOpt);
  }
}
```

So this part of code is exactly as in the example. I tried to change the `Option<Principal>` part to `UserLookupByUsername<Principal>` but then I get stuck a bit later. The entire code of my app can by found [here](https://github.com/LukaszTrojanowski/linkShepherdServer). The error occurs in [handlers.dart](https://github.com/LukaszTrojanowski/linkShepherdServer/blob/master/lib/handlers.dart).

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because `JwtSessionHandler` expects `lookupByUsername` function with only one parameter, not `lookupByUsernamePassword` which has two.